# Android Fragments - why are they so useful?

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, save, screen-rotation

I heard a lot of recommendation to use fragments in activities, but why is that? I know that fragments can be used when composing screen layouts for small and large device's screens. Is there something more for what can be fragments useful? Can they automatically save and restore state when rotating? Or something else?

Comment: Everything is there on the Internet. Try learning how to use Google Search first

Comment: I used it, but somehow i couldnt find a direct answer. Maybe because of my not very good english, but thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read a little bit more about fragments, here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

You can also look at the available methods so it is clearer what you can do, but I personally don't use fragments in simple apps, event for tablets, do fragments are like "divs" from html, they are just blocks/containers

Comment: Still cant figure out why are fragments so needy

Comment: simply : can you do a flexible website without divs ? maybe with spans or sections, yes, but divs are the main blocks of constructing a website, same thing are fragments for android + they got some more extras